# Facing double posting issue in JqWidgets context menu for nested grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I am facing double posting problem in JqWidgets context menu for nested grid. The event is getting fire n time (where "n" is no of time I clicked context menu)

Apart from this if I am keeping event handler method outside the context menu creation than on such case event handler is not getting called

**Scenario-1** (where I am getting double posting problem, unable to get selected row column value)

```
//handle context menu clicks.
var teamButtonClick = function (event) {

    try{

           // create context menu for Task
           var taskContextMenu = jQuery("#teamMenu").jqxMenu({ width: 160, height: 162, autoOpenPopup: false, mode: 'popup'});
           jQuery("#<portlet:namespace />teamGrid").on('contextmenu', function () {
               return false;
           });
           jQuery("#teamMenu").on('itemclick', function (event) {
               try {
                   var args = event.args;
                   var rowindex = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
                   if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(args).text().trim()) == "Add User") {
                        editrow = rowindex;
                        jQuery("#rowId").val(editrow);
                        var dataRecord = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);  
                        alert(dataRecord);                  
                    }
               }catch(e) {alert(e);}
           });

           var buttonID = event.target.id;      
           jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', buttonID);
           var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
           var scrollLeft = jQuery(window).scrollLeft();
           taskContextMenu.jqxMenu('open', parseInt(event.clientX) + 5 + scrollLeft, parseInt(event.clientY) + 5 + scrollTop);
           return false;
         }catch(e) {
            alert('error in contextmenu: ' + e);
         }
}
```

**Scenario-2** (where my event handler is not getting called when I am keeping outside context menu creation block)

```
// event handler is not getting called in this case
jQuery("#teamMenu").on('itemclick', function (event) {
   try {
       var args = event.args;
       var rowindex = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
       if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(args).text().trim()) == "Add User") {
            editrow = rowindex;
            jQuery("#rowId").val(editrow);
            var dataRecord = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);  
            alert(dataRecord);                  
        }
   }catch(e) {alert(e);}
});

//handle context menu clicks.
var teamButtonClick = function (event) {

    try{

           // create context menu for Task
           var taskContextMenu = jQuery("#teamMenu").jqxMenu({ width: 160, height: 162, autoOpenPopup: false, mode: 'popup'});
           jQuery("#<portlet:namespace />teamGrid").on('contextmenu', function () {
               return false;
           });

           var buttonID = event.target.id;      
           jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', buttonID);
           var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
           var scrollLeft = jQuery(window).scrollLeft();
           taskContextMenu.jqxMenu('open', parseInt(event.clientX) + 5 + scrollLeft, parseInt(event.clientY) + 5 + scrollTop);
           return false;
         }catch(e) {
            alert('error in contextmenu: ' + e);
         }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Event can be raised n times, only if you bind to it n times. Check your code how many times you call your teamButtonClick function which binds to "itemclick". It's more than 1 time if "itemclick" is called more than 1 time :)